# How to get working clickable HTML input under DIV layer?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a fixed `<input>` element placed beneath a `<div>` that has a background image. The `<div>` with a background image is thus placed over the input element, having some part of the background image transparent (designer's idea).

Is there any normal solution to being able to type some text in such input field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using CSS property `pointer-events: none` will do the trick.

Observe: http://jsfiddle.net/aymj6v9d/

This is currently supported by: *Chrome*, *Firefox*, *IE11*, *Opera* and *Safari*.
More information can be obtained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events